# Определенный шаблон вывода для указанной страницы (Drupal 8)?

Tags: drupal, drupal8

При создание страницы, хочется иметь возможность выбрать из списка нужный шаблон вывода.

1. Есть-ли готовое решение?
2. Какое альтернативное решение?

Например подобное реализовано в WordPress: создаем шаблон страницы > при создание страницы автоматически погружаются ранее созданные шаблоны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть желание посмотрите на этот модуль [Node Template Selector](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_template_selector)

Но реализация подобного функционала будет настолько простой что возможно не стоит брать модуль.

Например создаете в своего CONTENT_TYPE допольнительно поле Template (Машынное имя поля  должно быть **field_template**)
c возможными вариантами, например:

```
red
blue
green
```

*Нужно помнить что не надо писать самому шаблоны с нуля, найдите в ядре шаблон например node.html.twig возьмите оттуда код, скопируйте в свой шаблон и тогда изменяйте те детали которые вам нужны. Это нужно сделать для того чтобы не поломать например функционал ядра связанный с переменной*

```
{{ metadata }}
```

*А то потом зайдете в админку укажете метаданные какие то, а выводиться они не будут, потому что переменную вы удалили создавая свой новый темплейт.*

Потом в файле темы пишете следующий код

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_alter().
 */
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  // Типы в которых вы создадите поле
  $node_types = ['article', 'post', 'basic_page'];

  if($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')
    && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface
    // Здесь так же можете указать `html` вместо `node`
    // Тогда шаблон будет применяться ко всей странице,
    // а не только к контенту материала 
    && $hook == 'node'
    && !$node->get('field_template')->isEmpty()
    && in_array($node->getType(), $node_types)
  ){
     array_splice(
       $suggestions, count($suggestions) - 1, 
       0, 
       'node__' . $node->getType(). '__' . $node->get('field_template')->value
    );
  }
}
```

Потом в директории `templates` или как вам удобно например `templates/node`

создаете файлы вида

```
node--TYPE_NODE--FIELD_VALUE_TEMPLATE.html.twig
```

Пример:

```
node--article--red.html.twig
```

Это очень грубо и в общем написал, писал с головы не проверяя на практике, могут быть опечатки. Но в целом такая реализация вам может подойти.